how do I integrate python code in UltiSnips
I've written simple python code, which writes the String "< >" multiple times to stdout.
I would like to intergrate this in vim UltiSnips, but I don't know how to do it.
Here's my script:
def make_chords(num_reps):
    text = ""
    for i in range(num_reps):
        text += "< > "
    return text

A tip how to achieve my aim
